# Passing JSON (double-quoted elements and values) in Command Line Arguments in Gradle Java App on Windows

Tags: java, json, gradle, command-line-arguments, gradlew

I am trying to pass a JSON string command line argument into my Gradle Java app. The JSON parser is erroring because Gradle appears to be stripping the double-quotes in the JSON string. Take this code for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (String arg : args) {
        String msg = "commandline arg: " + arg;
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

...and the following outputs:

```
> java MyApp '{"firstName":"Rocky", "lastName":"Balboa"}'
commandline arg: {firstName:Rocky, lastName:Balboa}

> java MyApp '{\"firstName\":\"Rocky\", \"lastName\":\"Balboa\"}'
commandline arg: {"firstName":"Rocky", "lastName":"Balboa"}
```

Escaping with backslashes works fine through the JVM. However, not so much through Gradle:

```
> gradle clean execute -DmainClass='MyApp' --args='{"firstName":"Rocky","lastName":"Balboa"}'
commandline arg: {firstName:Rocky,lastName:Balboa}

> gradle clean execute -DmainClass='MyApp' --args='{\"firstName\":\"Rocky\",\"lastName\":\"Balboa\"}'
commandline arg: {firstName:Rocky,lastName:Balboa}
```

Is there a way to instruct Gradle to treat these double-quotes as literals?

Answer (score 1):

Try defining args in the JavaExec of build script

```
task run(type:JavaExec) {
    main = "com.abc.xyz.Main"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args System.getProperty("args")
    print("my args "+args);
}
```

and use gradle command - gradle run -Dargs="{"name": "xyz", "id":"123"}"